# Polymer Change Events on Sub-Property Changes

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0 supports [binding to structured data](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#path-binding) using dot syntax as demonstrated below:

```
<template>
  <div>{{user.manager.name}}</div>
</template>
```

In the above example, is there a way to get a [`<<property>>-changed` event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#change-notification-protocol) on the `user` property itself when any of it's sub-properties change? Right now, although the binding does update the sub-properties of `user`, my `user-changed` event listener only catches changes to the `user` property itself and does not catch changes to sub-properties.

Do I have to manually configure listeners for every single sub-property of the user element in order to listen to those events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to define a listener for every sub-property, though there is a shorter way to do it, by defining an observers array: [Observing sub-property changes](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties#observing-path-changes)